# How to change `acrylicOpacity` action in Windows Terminal Preview so it depends on the background colour under a terminal window?

Tags: json, terminal, windows-terminal

I know that I can modify my Terminal Preview json with `acrylicOpacity`, but when I have some stuff that is white/bright on the background, then it's hard to see console output.

I wonder, is it possible to somehow create the relation of the amount of transparency from `acrylicOpacity` based on the "background situation"?

Now it looks like this (you can see the dark background of the Stack Overflow):
[image: it's ok because the background is dark]
but (here, you can see the white background of notepad++):
[image: now it's not ok, because background is bright/white]

I'd like to have a feature to make the background of Windows Terminal Preview dark when a window under the WTP window is bright/white. In other words: I want to see the similar darkness on WTP (like on the picture n. one) with a lower layer which is bright/white.

Is there any easy way to do it?
Last thing: I like the level of transparency on the "dark surfaces", so it's not a matter of lower of transparency - **it's not my point**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not make the terminal detect when things behind it are bright and adapt at all.

You can add a dark background image with its own transparency so that when things are bright they aren't super bright.
Or pick a background colour or a different colour scheme that improves visibility in bright areas without taking away from how it looks in the dark.

There aren't really any options that can help you.

If you are asking for a feature you are probably better off opening an issue on [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) and discussing it there.